# Get di screenshot of the display

Tags: android, image, screenshot, runnable

Is it possible to get a screenshot of the display at any time with a background service.
This code enable only to capture the screenshot of my activity.

```
            View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
            v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
            v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Use the media projection APIs, available on Android 5.0 and higher. See the chapter entitled "The Media Projection APIs" in [this free older book](https://commonsware.com/Android/) for more. It reviews samples such as [this](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/MediaProjection/andshooter).

Answer (score 0):

To get screenshot of views not belonging to the app developed by you, use [MediaProjectionManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/projection/MediaProjection.html) .

But you have to first take the permission of the user to do so.

Note:  This is applicable for Android 5.0(Lolipop) onwards.